# Helm Templating in Configmap for values.yaml

Tags: templates, kubernetes-helm

I"m looking for help to create a generic configmap.yaml that can support several services.

values.yaml (THIS WORKS)

```
value1:  val1

genericConfigMapProperties:
  application.properties: |-
    prop1=prop1value
    prop2=prop2value
```

configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: 1
kind: ConfigMap
...
...
data:
{{ (toYaml .Values.genericConfigMapProperties)  . | ident 4 }}
```

The template `{{ (toYaml .Values.genericConfigMapProperties)  . | ident 4 }}` is almost perfect. It renders `application.properties` correctly:

```
data:
  application.properties: |-
    prop1=prop1value
    prop2=prop2value
```

values.yaml (THIS DOES NOT WORK)

```
value1:  val1

genericConfigMapProperties:
  cmValue1: {{ .Values.value1 | default "default val1" | quote }}

  application.properties: |-
    prop1=prop1value
    prop2=prop2value
```

It is getting errors rendering `cmValue1`.  I am expecting this answer:

```
data:
  cmValue1: val1

  application.properties: |-
    prop1=prop1value
    prop2=prop2value
```

Errors:

```
Error: failed to parse values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.value1 | default \"default val1\" | quote":interface {}(nill)}
helm.go:88: [debug]  error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.value1 | default \"default val1\" | quote":interface {}(nill)}
failed to parse values.yaml
```

What additional helm template code do I need to support `cmValue1` rendering?

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you write this content into the `templates/configmap.yml`; why the indirect path of specifying not just configuration but actual logic via Helm values?

Answer (score 1):

Helm does not support secondary rendering, but you can use **[yaml anchor](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/)** to achieve this function, or indirectly by using **[named templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/)**.

### Plan A : anchor

values.yaml

```yaml
value1: &value1 val1

genericConfigMapProperties:
  cmValue1: *value1

  application.properties: |-
    prop1=prop1value
    prop2=prop2value
```

templates/configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  config.yaml: |
    {{- toYaml $.Values.genericConfigMapProperties | nindent 4 }}
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  config.yaml: |
    application.properties: |-
      prop1=prop1value
      prop2=prop2value
    cmValue1: val1
```

### Plan B: Named Template

values.yaml

```yaml
value1: val1
```

templates/_helpers.tpl

```yaml
{{/*
cmValue template
*/}}
{{- define "genericConfigMapProperties" -}}
cmValue1: {{ .Values.value1 | default "default val1" | quote }}
application.properties: |-
  prop1=prop1value
  prop2=prop2value
{{- end -}}
```

templates/configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  config.yaml: |
     {{- include "genericConfigMapProperties" . | nindent 4 }}
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  config.yaml: |
    cmValue1: "val1"
    application.properties: |-
      prop1=prop1value
      prop2=prop2value
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for responding.

I've found this awesome solution from bitnami common templates.  It works just about anywhere.

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/common/templates/_tplvalues.tpl

Copy this template file:

```
{{/* vim: set filetype=mustache: */}}
{{/*
Renders a value that contains template.
Usage:
{{ include "common.tplvalues.render" ( dict "value" .Values.path.to.the.Value "context" $) }}
*/}}
{{- define "common.tplvalues.render" -}}
    {{- if typeIs "string" .value }}
        {{- tpl .value .context }}
    {{- else }}
        {{- tpl (.value | toYaml) .context }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

Use it to template any values in configmap.yaml or deployment.yaml or anywhere else...

values.yaml:

```
configMapProperties:
  cmValue1: "val1"
  application.properties: |-
    prop1=prop1value
    prop2=prop2value
```

configmap.yaml

```
data:
    {{- if .Values.configMapProperties }}
    {{- include "common.tplvalues.render" ( dict "value" .Values.configMapProperties "context" $ ) | nindent 2 }}
    {{- end }}
```